# Why does Verdana font result in a different space size before text depending on font?

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML/CSS example

http://jsfiddle.net/Hmwvv/

we can notice a leading space with size proportional to font's size. How can I remove this effect in order to have different sized texts in different `div` elements aligned ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small amount of white space around each glyph, this is intentional so that the letters don't overlap. You can see this by selecting one letter.

To solve your problem, introduce a small negative `text-indent`.

```
#big {
    text-indent: -5px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmwvv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The leading space is part of the character rendering, as you can see e.g. by setting `div:first-letter { background: green }. It would violate normal typographic rules to tweak it.

But if you really want to align the leftmost strokes of letter “M” in different sizes in a heading and in the first line of a paragraph after it, then setting `margin-left: 0.3em` on the paragraph would seem to be the best option. This applies Verdana and those specific characters are used. (If e.g. the first letter of the heading is “J”, the situation is very different.)